# Openmp parallel do loop working correctly ~50% of the time

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am currently working on adding openmp parallelization for a do loop in one of the codes I have written for research. I am fairly new to using openmp so I would appreciate if you had any suggestions for what might be going wrong.

Basically, I have added a parallel do loop to the following code (which works prior to parallelization). r(:,:,:,:) is a vector of a ton of molecular coordinates indexed by time, molecule, atom, and (xyz). This vector is about 100 gb of data (I am working on an HPC with plenty of RAM). I am trying to parallelize the outer loop and subdivide it between processors so that I can reduce the amount of time this calculation goes. I thought it would be a good one to do it with as msd and cm_msd are the only things that would need to be edited by multiple processors and stored for later, which since each iteration gets its own element of these arrays they won't have a race condition.

The problem: If I run this code 5 times I get varying results, sometimes msd is calculated correctly (or appears to be), and sometimes it outputs all zeros later when I average it together. Without parallelization there are no issues.

I have been trying altering the shared vs private variables in the code and I think I have accounted for everything. The i index of the msd array and msd_cm array should never be equivalent between threads so I would think that they wouldn't be an issue.

```
! Loop over time origins
    counti = 0
    ind = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO schedule(static) PRIVATE(i,j,k,it,r_old,r_cm_old,shift,shift_cm,dsq,ind) &
    !$OMP& SHARED(msd,msd_cm)
    do i=1, nconfigs-nt, or_int
        if(MOD(counti*or_int,500) == 0) then
            write(*,*) 'Reached the ', counti*or_int,'th time origin'
        end if
        ! Set the Old Coordinates
        counti = counti + 1
        ind = (i-1)/or_int + 1
        r_old(:,:,:) = r(i,:,:,:)
        r_cm_old(:,:) = r_cm(i,:,:)
        shift = 0.0
        shift_cm = 0.0

        ! Loop over the timesteps in each trajectory
        do it=i+2, nt+i
            ! Loop over molecules
            do j = 1, nmols
                do k=1, atms_per_mol
                    ! Calculate the shift if it occurs.
                    shift(j,k,:) = shift(j,k,:) - L(:)*anint((r(it,j,k,:) - &
                        r_old(j,k,:) )/L(:))
                    ! Calculate the square displacements
                    dsq = ( r(it,j,k,1) + shift(j,k,1) - r(i,j,k,1) ) ** 2. &
                         +( r(it,j,k,2) + shift(j,k,2) - r(i,j,k,2) ) ** 2. &
                         +( r(it,j,k,3) + shift(j,k,3) - r(i,j,k,3) ) ** 2.
                    msd(ind, it-1-i, k) = msd(ind, it-1-i, k) + dsq
                    ! Calculate the contribution to the c1,c2
                enddo ! End Atoms Loop (k)
                ! Calculate the shift if it occurs.
                shift_cm(j,:) = shift_cm(j,:) - L(:)*anint((r_cm(it,j,:) - &
                                r_cm_old(j,:) )/L(:))
                ! Calculate the square displacements
                dsq = ( r_cm(it,j,1) + shift_cm(j,1) - r_cm(i,j,1) ) ** 2. &
                    +( r_cm(it,j,2) + shift_cm(j,2) - r_cm(i,j,2) ) ** 2. &
                    +( r_cm(it,j,3) + shift_cm(j,3) - r_cm(i,j,3) ) ** 2.
                msd_cm(ind,it-1-i) = msd_cm(ind, it-1-i) + dsq
            enddo ! End Molecules Loop (j)
            r_old(:,:,:) = r(it,:,:,:)
            r_cm_old(:,:) = r_cm(it,:,:)
       enddo ! End t's loop (it)
    enddo
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

When this code is run, when I later print the averaged msd results out they either come out as correctly or they come out as zero and it is always one or the other. Do you see an issue that might explain why it is only working part of the time. I am brand new to openmp so it is completely possible there is just something incredibly stupid with how I am trying to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dumping a whole bunch of code in here and asking: "Why isn't this working" is not a good way to get help. Please reduce it to a minimal example. When code is working sometimes and sometimes not, it's often a race condition, particularly with parallel programming. In this case, I would suspect the lines where values are assigned to the shared arrays `msd` and `msd_cm` without protecting them by an `critical` or `atomic` directive.

Comment: Yes, it very much looks like a race condition. I suspect changing the scoping of msd and msd_cm from shared to a reduction over + will fix this, but without a complete program  demonstrating the problem it is impossible to test and say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my question, this is the first time I posted on SO and so I didn't realize I hadn't paired it down enough. It was indeed a race condition involving msd and msd_cm which I was able to solve via a reduction and by adding a default(none) directive to force myself to identify all the shared/private vars. Thanks again!